# How to exit a "cordova build" command from a hook?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I use Cordova with a hook on after_prepare.
I want to exit if the command is not correct.

For example, this command is correct :

```
cordova run android --ENV=PRD
```

This one is incorrect and I want the lifecycle of Cordova be interrupted :

```
cordova run android --ENV=AEZAZEZ
```

My hook looks like :

```
module.exports = function(ctx) {

var env     = ctx.opts.options.ENV;

if ( !CONFIG[env] ) {
    // there is a problem in the CLI, I want to exit

} else {
```

How to modify a hook to exit from Cordova run command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throw an unhandled exception:

```
if ( !CONFIG[env] ) {
    throw "there is a problem in the CLI, I want to exit";
}
```