# Cordova stop build from hook

Tags: cordova, mobile, build, hook

I have several hooks for my cordova app. Now i would like to stop the build if any of my beforeBuild hook crashes. Is there anything like an `exit(1)` possible to use in the hook to tell cordova to stop the build or can i just throw an error in my hook?

Does anyone have an idea? An example would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45163424/how-to-exit-a-cordova-build-command-from-a-hook

Comment: Sadly that's not working for me. With this just the hook is cancelled but not the complete build.